# Change Cell Color in DatagridView when BindingList causes value change

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I would like to intercept the event of the DataGridView being updated after a change in a BindingList, so I can change the color of the changed cell.
I noticed that CellValueChanged is never fired in this case (according to msdn this is only fired when there is user interaction)

Answer (score 0):

You Could listen to ListChanged of the BindingList ,
and change cell formatting from there ?

Edit:
using the OldIndex you can get the old value , retrieve some key unique attribute , using that attribute find the correct row in the grid.
You should probably have some unique key column in a grid for this purpose. you can make this column hidden .
ref:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.listchangedeventargs.aspx

Comment: Yes but how to detect which cell has been changed ?